# Ruby not inputting text in text field from excel file

Tags: ruby, excel, selenium

I have a spreadsheet with both valid and invalid login combinations. I wrote the test in Selenium using Ruby to pass the username and password to text fields in the website I am testing.

It isn't inputting the username and password. In fact, the test seems stuck on a continuous loop and does not end, while it is still focused on the login window.

Below is the snippet of code I'm having issue with:

```
require "win32ole"

xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = true
xl.displayAlerts = false
wb = xl.Workbooks.open("C:/.../login.xlsx")
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
ws.select

rows = 2
while rows <= 3
  username = ws.Cells(rows, "A").text
  password = ws.Cells(rows, "B").text
end

#invalid login
@driver.find_element(:id, "tbLUser").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "tbLUser").send_keys(username)
@driver.find_element(:id, "tbLPass").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "tbLPass").send_keys(password)
assert element_present?(:name, "lg5_login")
@driver.find_element(:name, "lg5_login").click
```

Can anyone help me get past this hangup in this code, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: Of course it'll be an **infinite loop** as `rows` value is not being changed in your `while` loop and condition will always be `true`.

Comment: How would I change that to keep it from being an infinite loop?

Comment: first, what's `rows` and what was the reason behind that `while` loop? it's hard to say anything without a proper understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I honestly don't know why I was directed to make it a while loop. I only have 2 rows: one for invalid login and one for a valid login. I'm wanting to expand this test later to use a random list of usernames and passwords. Plus, it keeps from entering real-time passwords in static code.

Comment: Why does the comment says "invalid login" if you have valid and invalid credentials in your sheet? If you want to test the invalid path only, just get rid of the loop and load the invalid credentials. If you want to test multiple paths, create multiple tests or test each loaded credential *inside* the loop (increment the `rows` value at the end of each iteration). But your sheet should also provide a boolean column like "valid?" to know what to expect in each test result.

Comment: #invalid login is something I did not delete from this code after pasting it. What I want to do is to have a spreadsheet with valid and invalid login options that will be tested. There are two sections in my code: invalid and valid. The invalid verifies text displayed after an invalid login, whereas the valid login goes to a longer line of code to verify multiple pages. I don't want built in username and password as those change. I wanted a spreadsheet that could change. The boolean is a good idea, but I'm so new to this that I don't know where to begin. In other words, I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your code without being too invasive, you could try something like that:

```
(2..ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).each do |row|  # go through each row with data
  username = ws.Cells(row, "A").Value
  password = ws.Cells(row, "B").Value
  is_valid = ws.Cells(row, "C").Value   # 3rd column with TRUE/FALSE boolean values

  @driver.find_element(:id, "tbLUser").clear
  @driver.find_element(:id, "tbLUser").send_keys(username)
  @driver.find_element(:id, "tbLPass").clear
  @driver.find_element(:id, "tbLPass").send_keys(password)
  assert element_present?(:name, "lg5_login")
  @driver.find_element(:name, "lg5_login").click
  # One method for each case, an if/else with an inline check would also be fine
  is_valid ? assert_valid_result : assert_invalid_result
end
```

Comment: Thank you! The only problem I have right now is that it is not recognizing username as a variable, even though it is defined above.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. My end statement was in the wrong place. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `while` loop here as you just want to iterate over the number of rows in your Excel sheet. You can use: `times`:

```
rows = 2
rows.times do
  username = ws.Cells(rows, "A").text
  password = ws.Cells(rows, "B").text
end

# your rest of the code
```

One thing I want to point out here is that in `rows.times` your `username` and `password` will be over-written by the last iteration of the block. To prevent that you can create a hash:

```
rows = 2
users = rows.times.with_object({}){ |i, u| u["row #{i+1}"] = { 'username' => 'd', 'password' => 'r' } }
```

Now, you can access your users with credentials row-wise:

```
users['row 1']['username'] #=> 'user 1'
users['row 2']['username'] #=> 'user 2'
```